# Would it be any beneficial to read old books on computer networking

Tags: network

I want to self study computer networking and have found computer networking a top down approach to be a good start but as I have to get a pdf (for the reason the physical book is much expensive) I got a 6ed which is of around 2012 . Would it be good to read from it or I have to buy the latest edition.

The same question is for the computer science books.

Thanks in advance . .....

Comment: Sadly, questions that tend to generate a lot of opinions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

None of the fundamentals have changed for a long time, and until you have a good grasp of the fundamentals you won't properly understand the things which are genuinely new.

Many contributors to this forum have equipment with uptime older than that book; probably all of us use some equipment older than that.

You'll definitely learn lots from such a book, don't worry about its age.

Comment: Does it apply to security courses and penetration testing courses available at cybrary or some good old books.